# Strongly-Typed SignalR Hub in Angular 6

Tags: c#, angular, typescript, asp.net-core-signalr

*Too Long; Didn't Read:*
How does one implement a strongly-typed SignalR hub (custom methods) in Angular 6?

---

Ultimately, I'm trying to use a Strongly-Typed SignalR Hub in Angular 6 using services and interfaces.  I'll start with the Hub first.  Since SignalR has the option to now strongly-typed commands, I'd like to use these for better securing data.  I wouldn't mind also having a way to do authentication, but that may be a story for a different time.

*ApHub.cs*

```cs
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using AckermanPuglisi.Thesaurus;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR;

namespace Tinhalo.Hubs {
    public class ApHub : Hub<INlgClient> {
        private readonly IApContext _apContext;

        public ApHub(IApContext apContext) {
            _apContext = apContext;
        }

        public async Task GetTraits() {
            await Clients.Caller.GetAllTraits(_apContext.Traits);
        }

        public async Task GetEmotions() {
            await Clients.Caller.GetAllEmotions(_apContext.Emotions);
        }

        public async Task ConnectionMessage() {
            await Clients.Caller.CheckConnection("You are connected");
        }
    }
}
```

From there, I create the interface for SignalR to have the typed methods that I'll need to call in Angular.  I've made the models already in a models folder, but I'll leave out the details on that because I'm not sure if they are relevant.

*INlgClient.cs*

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using AckermanPuglisi.Thesaurus.Data.Graph.Models;

namespace Tinhalo.Hubs {
    public interface INlgClient {
        Task GetAllTraits(ICharacterTrait[] apContextTraits);
        Task GetTrait(ICharacterTrait trait);
        Task GetAllEmotions(Emotion[] apContextEmotions);
        Task GetEmotion(Emotion emotion);   
        Task GetTraitEmotions(string traitName);
        Task CheckConnection(string connectMessage);
    }
}
```

---

These previous two things work for sure when they are un-typed.  After that, I do some stuff in Angular 6, namely the service (which I've found out you can't start() the hub connection until you have `window` defined... else you get a XMLHttpRequest undefined error)

*signal.service.ts*

```js
import { Injectable, Inject, OnInit, AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';
import { HubConnection, HubConnectionBuilder, JsonHubProtocol } from "@aspnet/signalr";
import { Emotion } from '../models/emotion.model';
import { Trait } from '../models/trait.model';
import * as signalr from '@aspnet/signalr';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
    providedIn: "root"
})
export class SignalService {
    public aphub: HubConnection;

    public hubConnected: any;

    constructor(@Inject('BASE_URL') baseUrl: string) {
        let options = {
            transport: signalr.HttpTransportType.WebSockets
                | signalr.HttpTransportType.LongPolling,
            AccessTokenFactory: async () => {
                // Get and return the access token.
                // This function can return a JavaScript Promise if asynchronous
                // logic is required to retrieve the access token.
            }
        };
        let protocol = new signalr.JsonHubProtocol();

        this.aphub = new signalr.HubConnectionBuilder()
            .configureLogging(signalr.LogLevel.Trace)
            .withUrl(`${baseUrl}aphub`, options)
            .withHubProtocol(protocol).build();
    }
}
```

Now, if I do `this.aphub.getTraits((traits) => { ... });` which is the equivalent to `hub.invoke('getTraits' ... )`, it'll say that the method isn't defined at design-time but will show up on inspection during run time.  This tells me that I totally need an interface for this - which I sorta have.  I think the big issue is that I'll likely be able to implement my custom methods on the new class, but I don't know what I must custom implement because of the mix of private/internal stuff to SignalR HubConnections.

I may not even be implementing the right object, even.

*aphub.interface.ts*

```js
import { HubConnection } from "@aspnet/signalr";

interface IAphub extends HubConnection {
    getTraits(): void;
    getTrait(traitName: string): void;
    getTraitEmotions(traitName: string): void;
    getEmotions(): void;
    getEmotion(emotionName: string): void;
    connectionMessage(): void;
}

class ApHub implements IAphub {
  /* What goes here? */
}
```

---

Please be kind, I'm fairly new to Angular itself but I get definitely get the C# part of it.  I've been in MVC for quite a while - Typescript is a bit new to me, but I get most of it.  SignalR seems the best way to go about asynchronous data because it has more than `.Caller`, but also `.Broadcast` which will come in handy later on down the line.

Google has a tonne of stuff on Angular, but with Angular 1.x, Angular 2.x, and all of the versioning confusion (ng-thing vs. ng2-thing vs. ngx-thing plus stuff with `$` and `$scope` and again with dumptrucks full of Angular 4.x code), I just want to find an answer for my AspNetCore 2.1 (to be 3.0), SignalR@latest, and Angular 6 website.

---

I have tried to generate an interface using SignalR.exe, but it doesn't work saying it is missing a manifest - which is likely because it is a dotnet core application.

Comment: I suggest you try putting a TLDR version with an actual question. I've skimmed the question but the only _question_ you have is a comment `What does here?`.

Comment: Added the topper - I had thought the title would've been the TL;DR.